# Multiple Google Maps icons?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to combine the following two blocks of codes together.

but for some reason, when i load the page in the browser, First the second blocks of code loads the marker on the map and then the page refreshes and the first blocks of code loads on the map!

This is my entire code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google maps</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>

     var map;
     geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

     function initialize() {
         var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
         };

         map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);

         codeAddress();
     }

     function codeAddress() {
         var address = '<?= $_GET['location'] ?>';
         geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
             if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                 map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      icon: 'meicon.png',
                      map: map,
                      position: results[0].geometry.location
                 });
             } else {
                alert("Error loading map");
             }
         });
     }
     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var locations = [
        ['Bondi Beach', 51.5033631,-0.1276253, 1]
    ];
    var maps = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
      zoom: 15,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5033630,-0.1276250),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var markers, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      markers = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: maps
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(markers, 'click', (function(markers, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, markers);
        }
      })(markers, i));
    }
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

could someone please advise on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are creating two different maps.  What did you want to have happen when you "combined the functionality?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you're calling the geocoder on the address in the first block, which is an async call to google to check the address. While the code is talking to google the page runs the second code block. When that call returns it runs the rest of the code in the first block, which sets the center of the map.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is simple you are loading  two map the first called in `<head>` script what  build a map in map-canvas named `map`.  the second in body script  you create another map named `maps` and this too create in `map-canvas`.You need  only a working map and with this do what you nedd.